# Python help - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'

Tags: python, import, module, argparse, attributeerror

I need help with something that should be basic. Using the example from  [Python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse) I am encountering the following error

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

A print argparse.__ file__ confirmed that it is calling the correct argparse.py file:
File "C:\Python27\lib\argparse.py", line 86, in

Also I made sure there are no nameclashes withother modules. Infact, just removing everything else from the script still calls this error.

Have tried reinstalling python 2.7.9 with no change.

Help this noob please!

Answer (score 3):

It's because your file name is the same as the module name. Rename your file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

so, I had:
from numpy import *

and I changed this to import numpy and it didn't work.

Then I copied all the test verbatim and made a new .py file and saved it out.
Now it works.

thank you Python. I think i'll stick to C!! :S

Comment: Your question was about the `argparse` module, but now you are talking about `numpy`!  They are unrelated modules.  With `C` you still have to make sure all the necessary libraries are present and referenced in the `.h` files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's wrong. It may be unavailable in the release of Python 2.7 that you're using. Try installing Python 2.7.8 or 2.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

When importing modules, python usually first looks for them in your current Path, and only if it can't find them there, it will then look in the other Python-paths (found in [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)).

Like Daniel Roche said, You obviously named your script "argparse.py" (thinking this would be a good name for an example on how to use argparse, an intuitive and common mistake, I think) and then basically told your script to import itself (how rude).

... And since your script does not have an "ArgumentParser" method defined, this must of course yield an Error.